# Sum of prime factors

Tags: c

I am trying to show the sum of the prime factors of a given number and
I'm having difficulties displaying the prime factors in my output.

Sample Output:

```
Input number: 6
Factors are: 1 2 3
Sum of its factor: 1 +2 +3 =6
```

I am able to show the sum but I want to show the `1+2+3=6` like in the sample above where the factors are `1 2 3`.

Can you help me correct my syntax to achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int i, j, num, isPrime, sum;

    printf("Input number: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);

    printf("Factors are: ", num);

    for (i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
        if (num % i == 0) {
            isPrime = 1;
            for (j = 2; j <= i / 2; j++) {
                if (i % j == 0) {
                    isPrime = 0;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (isPrime == 1) {
                printf("%d ", i);
                sum += i;
            }
        }
    }

    printf("\nSum of its factor : %d", sum);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you show what output you got ?

Comment: And in the line: `printf("Factors are: ", num); `, you should remove the `num` that you don't want to print there I think

Comment: Curious. You (or your professor) seem to have chosen a fairly restrictive example number (6) as it doesn't amplify the real intent of whether you want sum of  *unique* prime factors, or just sum of all primes in the prime factorization of the input number. Ex: 8 has only one prime factor (2) (excluding 1), but it appears *three* times in the prime factorization of 8. So would you want the answer to be 2, or 6? Anyway, not sure if that was made clear in your assignment, but may be worth looking at further.

Comment: 1 is not a prime factor. The prime factors of 6 are 2 and 3 only.

Comment: All positive numbers are divisible by one which is why it's not a factor.

Comment: @tadman 1 is a factor of all numbers, but it is not a prime.

Comment: @klutt Yes, a better definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code actually has undefined behavior because `sum` is not initialized to `0`. It produces the correct sum only by chance.

You can store the factors in an array, or even construct the expression as you go with `sprintf`. The maximum length of the expression is not very large as there can be at most 9 different prime factors (29!! > 2<sup>32</sup>)

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char expr[9 * 11 + 1];
    int i, j, pos, num, isPrime, sum;

    printf("Input number: ");
    if (scanf("%d", &num) != 1)
        return 1;

    printf("Factors are: 1");  // always include 1
    pos = 0;
    expr[pos] = '\0';
    sum = 1;
    for (i = 2; i <= num; i++) {
        if (num % i == 0) {
            isPrime = 1;
            for (j = 2; j * j <= i; j++) {
                if (i % j == 0) {
                    isPrime = 0;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (isPrime == 1) {
                pos += sprintf(expr + pos, "+%d", i);
                printf(" %d", i);
                sum += i;
            }
        }
    }

    printf("\nSum of its factors: 1%s = %d\n", expr, sum);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Input number: 6
Factors are: 1 2 3
Sum of its factors: 1+2+3 = 6
```

Here is a more robust and much faster version that does not have undefined behavior for very large values of `num`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char expr[9 * 11 + 1];
    int i, pos, num;
    unsigned sum;

    printf("Input number: ");
    if (scanf("%i", &num) != 1)
        return 1;

    printf("Factors are: 1");  // always include 1
    pos = 0;
    expr[pos] = '\0';
    sum = 1;
    for (i = 2; num / i >= i; i++) {
        if (num % i == 0) {
            pos += sprintf(expr + pos, "+%d", i);
            printf(" %d", i);
            sum += i;
            do { num /= i; } while (num % i == 0);
        }
    }
    if (num != 1) {
        pos += sprintf(expr + pos, "+%d", num);
        printf(" %d", num);
        sum += num;
    }
    printf("\nSum of its factors: 1%s = %u\n", expr, sum);
    return 0;
}
```

Test:

```
Input number: 0x7fffffff
Factors are: 1 2147483647
Sum of its factors: 1+2147483647 = 2147483648
```

Comment: `j * j <= i` has the disadvantage of potential `int` overflow. `j <= i/j` does not and since code has `i % j`, good compilers will compute the quotient and remainder efficiently together.  (no  real extra cost for the quotient)

Comment: `for (i = 2; i <= num; i++)` could OF too. Hmmm.

Comment: @chux: indeed for `num = 0x7fffffff`, which is prime, both statements will likely cause UB because of arithmetic overflow, and another overflow when computing the `sum` as `1+2147483647`. I posted a more robust version.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to print all the prime factors twice, you should do that in a way so that you can avoid duplicated code. Here is an idea:

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* Return the smallest prime that is smaller than or equal to n */
/* Assumes that the argument is greater than 1 */
int getFirst(int n)
{
    int i;
    for(i = 2; i <= n; i++)
        if(n % i == 0)
            return i;
}

int main()
{
    int num, x, tmp, sum=0;
    scanf("%d", &num);
    tmp = num;

    printf("Factors are: ");
    while(1) {
        x = getFirst(tmp);
        printf("%d ", x);
        if (x == tmp) /* If we are at the last prime */
            break;
        tmp /= x;
    }
    printf("\n");

    printf("Sum of factors is: ");
    tmp = num;
    while(1) {
        x = getFirst(tmp);
        printf("%d ", x);
        sum += x;
        if(x == tmp) /* If we are at the last prime */
            break;
        printf("+ ");
        tmp /= x;
    }
    printf("= %d\n", sum);
}
```

But as has been pointed out in the comments. 1 is not a prime, and that's why I excluded it.